# Merge 2 tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, merge

I would like to merge to tables in MySQL. In SQL I would use the 'MERGE' command, but what is the equivalent command in MySQL? Lets say i have 3 columns in both tables. Then i want to match the rows by the first column, and if there is a match it needs to update 2nd column but keep the original 3rd column and if there isnt a match then it needs to insert the new row.

[image]

Here is the SQL code I would like to convert to MySQL.

```
MERGE [Synsbasen].[dbo].[Koeretoej] AS T
USING [Synsbasen].[dbo].[KoeretoejLoad] AS S ON (T.KoeretoejIdent = S.KoeretoejIdent)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT(KoeretoejIdent, KoeretoejArtNavn, KoeretoejAnvendelseNavn, RegistreringNummerNummer, KoeretoejOplysningStatus, KoeretoejOplysningFoersteRegistreringDato, KoeretoejOplysningStelNummer, KoeretoejMaerkeTypeNavn, KoeretoejModelTypeNavn, KoeretoejVariantTypeNavn, DrivkraftTypeNavn, SynResultatSynsType, SynResultatSynsDato, SynResultatSynStatusDato, SidsteSynTjek) 
        VALUES(S.KoeretoejIdent, S.KoeretoejArtNavn, S.KoeretoejAnvendelseNavn, S.RegistreringNummerNummer, S.KoeretoejOplysningStatus, S.KoeretoejOplysningFoersteRegistreringDato, S.KoeretoejOplysningStelNummer, S.KoeretoejMaerkeTypeNavn, S.KoeretoejModelTypeNavn, S.KoeretoejVariantTypeNavn, S.DrivkraftTypeNavn, S.SynResultatSynsType, S.SynResultatSynsDato, S.SynResultatSynStatusDato, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'1900-01-01',110))
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET 
         T.KoeretoejArtNavn = S.KoeretoejArtNavn,
         T.KoeretoejAnvendelseNavn = S.KoeretoejAnvendelseNavn,
         T.RegistreringNummerNummer = S.RegistreringNummerNummer,
         T.KoeretoejOplysningStatus = S.KoeretoejOplysningStatus,
         T.KoeretoejOplysningFoersteRegistreringDato = S.KoeretoejOplysningFoersteRegistreringDato,
         T.KoeretoejOplysningStelNummer = S.KoeretoejOplysningStelNummer,
         T.KoeretoejMaerkeTypeNavn = S.KoeretoejMaerkeTypeNavn,
         T.KoeretoejModelTypeNavn = S.KoeretoejModelTypeNavn,
         T.KoeretoejVariantTypeNavn = S.KoeretoejVariantTypeNavn,
         T.DrivkraftTypeNavn = S.DrivkraftTypeNavn,
         T.SynResultatSynsType = S.SynResultatSynsType,
         T.SynResultatSynsDato = S.SynResultatSynsDato,
         T.SynResultatSynStatusDato = S.SynResultatSynStatusDato;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html
Your query should be something like this:

```
INSERT into Koeretoej
       (KoeretoejIdent, KoeretoejArtNavn, KoeretoejAnvendelseNavn,
        RegistreringNummerNummer, KoeretoejOplysningStatus,
        KoeretoejOplysningFoersteRegistreringDato, KoeretoejOplysningStelNummer,
        KoeretoejMaerkeTypeNavn, KoeretoejModelTypeNavn, KoeretoejVariantTypeNavn,
        DrivkraftTypeNavn, SynResultatSynsType, SynResultatSynsDato,
        SynResultatSynStatusDato, SidsteSynTjek)
SELECT
        S.KoeretoejIdent, S.KoeretoejArtNavn, S.KoeretoejAnvendelseNavn,
        S.RegistreringNummerNummer, S.KoeretoejOplysningStatus,
        S.KoeretoejOplysningFoersteRegistreringDato,
        S.KoeretoejOplysningStelNummer, S.KoeretoejMaerkeTypeNavn,
        S.KoeretoejModelTypeNavn, S.KoeretoejVariantTypeNavn,
        S.DrivkraftTypeNavn, S.SynResultatSynsType, S.SynResultatSynsDato,
        S.SynResultatSynStatusDato, DATE_FORMAT("19000101","%m-%d-%Y")
FROM KoeretoejLoad S LEFT JOIN Koeretoej T ON 
     T.KoeretoejIdent = S.KoeretoejIdent
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        KoeretoejArtNavn=S.KoeretoejArtNavn,
        KoeretoejAnvendelseNavn=S.KoeretoejAnvendelseNavn,
        RegistreringNummerNummer=S.RegistreringNummerNummer,
        KoeretoejOplysningStatus=S.KoeretoejOplysningStatus,
        KoeretoejOplysningFoersteRegistreringDato=S.KoeretoejOplysningFoersteRegistreringDato,
        KoeretoejOplysningStelNummer=S.KoeretoejOplysningStelNummer,
        KoeretoejMaerkeTypeNavn=S.KoeretoejMaerkeTypeNavn,
        KoeretoejModelTypeNavn=S.KoeretoejModelTypeNavn,
        KoeretoejVariantTypeNavn=S.KoeretoejVariantTypeNavn,
        DrivkraftTypeNavn=S.DrivkraftTypeNavn,
        SynResultatSynsType=S.SynResultatSynsType,
        SynResultatSynsDato=S.SynResultatSynsDato,
        SynResultatSynStatusDato=S.SynResultatSynStatusDato,
        SidsteSynTjek=DATE_FORMAT("19000101","%m-%d-%Y")
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks correct! I'll test it later today!